# What's the in-universe relevance for the name of Spider-Man: Homecoming?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-homecoming, title-explanation

The out-of-universe reason looks obvious. Marvel celebrated the fact that it can work with Spider-Man again after it sold its movie rights to Sony.

But, if you look at other movies in MCU, names viz. The First Avenger, The Dark World, Ragnarok etc reflect in-universe things. What does *Homecoming* signify in-universe?

Comment: This is in no way vague or unclear if you're alive while the movie is playing.

Comment: @phantom42 Actually I hadn't realized it was referring to the dance, either.  It does make sense in retrospect, though.

Comment: In universe the characters are not in a movie. Therefore "Spiderman:Homecoming" is not a movie title, and does not need an explanation.

Comment: *Harry Potter and the Yule Ball*

Comment: @phantom42 maybe I'm just tired, but I was more confused by your comment than the question

Comment: Off-topic, but if I could give +1 to your profile description I would ;)

Comment: @phanton42 Perhaps in other parts of the world people might not know what a homecoming dance is.

Comment: Isnt is obvious? It refers to him coming home after the events of Captain America... doesnt it?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This was addressed in [an interview](http://uk.ign.com/videos/2016/07/11/spider-man-homecoming-sony-pictures-boss-tom-rothman-interview) with the chairman of Sony Pictures, Tom Rothman.

> [Homecoming is] *relevant to the story because it takes place in high school and
> **there is a scene — that I guess I can give a little thing — at a
> homecoming dance.** I’ve actually seen the dailies of it because we
> already did the high school shooting of it in the first couple weeks
> and it’s fantastic. **But it’s also a homecoming to Marvel. And a
> homecoming to the cinematic universe that Spider-Man belongs in.** So
> it’s a pretty unprecedented deal between two studios, but we’re really
> proud of it. And all I can tell you is, those guys at Marvel — I think
> the technical term is — they know their sh-t.*
>
> <sub><sup>[‘Spider-Man: Homecoming’ Title Explained By Sony Head Tom Rothman](http://www.slashfilm.com/spider-man-homecoming-title/)</sup></sub>

[image]

Comment: Is this screenshot from one of the trailers?

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd - I believe so. I got it from the MCU wiki. The filename has the word "trailer" in it. http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/File:SMH_Trailer_09.png

Answer (score 44):

## Homecoming refers to the high school dance Peter attends in the film

(I haven't seen the film yet so I'm trying to avoid spoilers for myself and others.)

A [homecoming dance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homecoming) is a common high school tradition, and Peter, as a high school student, attends one during the film. It is featured as [the setting for the final act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man:_Homecoming#Plot). This is what the film's title refers to.

Comment: Cultural reference: 4th line of the chorus of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5qtW1jAwZgU&t=1m25s

Answer (score 7):

To add on to the previous answers, the homecoming dance is a major plot point in the film:

> At that critical scene, he makes the decision between his love interest, Liz, and stopping Vulture from his criminal activities.

But it's worse than that, because

> Vulture, not to be clichéd or anything, turns out to be Liz's father. (To break the cliché, though, Liz doesn't know of either her father's or Peter's alter egos.) It's because of that homecoming dance that Vulture finds out who Spiderman really is.

I'm sure someone out there is still trying to connect homecoming to the Winter Soldier command words:

> Longing, Rusted, Seventeen, Daybreak, Furnace, Nine, Benign, **Homecoming**, One, Freight Car. Good morning, Soldier.

Comment: The screenwriters of *The Winter Soldier* have stated that the "homecoming" was done "fairly accidentally" and not as a foreshadowing or easter egg. https://youtu.be/bPDE25VZwno?t=1m12s

Comment: @phantom42 Which is why I phrased that sentence the way I did. I didn't say that there *was* a connection, just that someone is probably still trying to come up with one.

Comment: I understand that, and I'm just offering up info to anyone that *is* trying to do so, that the screenwriters have denied this already.

Answer (score 3):

The beginning of the movie has Peter return home after Spiderman's huge debut into the world of superheroes, both fighting with and against Avengers at the airport (Captain America : Civil War).

Instead of his world being completely changed, everything is essentially back to normal.  Before being drafted by Tony Stark, he had already been a bit of a minor vigilante and he returns to that when he fails to receive the "Avenger" missions he wants and expects.

At the end of the movie, he comes full circle and returns home again.

> He rejects Tony's offer to become a full-time Avenger and returns home to be the *friendly neighborhood* Spiderman.

The Homecoming Dance came across to me as simply being a play on the word "Homecoming" rather than being the reason for the title.  Using any other semi-formal or formal dance would have made no change to the story.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason, in addition to the blatantly obvious ball, mentioned by others, is that

> after being fired from the "internship" with mister Tony Stark, 
>  he is welcomed back to Avengers at the end.

And don't forget

> the cliffhanger with aunt May after coming home at the end ...

Also

> it could mean coming back to his roots (school, ordinary things, less superheroing)

... or all of the above.